# How do i convert "[object Object]" to a number

Tags: javascript

I have been set a task, using an external IFFE file, to create an app that works out the cost of fuel for a fleet of cars using the functions inside the IFFE. Then display it in a box.

The IFFE can be see [Here](http://jack-stiles-online.co.uk/js/fuelCalculator.js), i have been told by the people that set me the task that the following code should work to call the correct function

```
var fuel = new fuelCalc();


// On the button press
miles = 10000;
var cost = fuel.cost(miles);
```

Then doing the following should put it into the text box,

```
document.getElementById("TotalCost").value = cost;
```

However, all it does is put the following in the text box

[object Object]

What do i need to add to make it show the calculated amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a year e.g. `document.getElementById("TotalCost").value = cost[2013];`

Comment: _Total_ suggests to me that OP may want them added up

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it looks like your function fuelCalc.cost is actually returning an object though.

Do you need to do further calculations within the function, maybe:

```
fuelCalc.prototype.cost = function ( annualMileage, start, end ) {
    var costPerLitre = this.costPerLitre;
    var averageMPG = this.averageMPG;

    var startYear = start || 1989;
    var endYear = end || 2020;
    var totalYears = endYear - startYear;

    var data = {};
            var totalCost = 0;

    for (var year = startYear, t = endYear; year <= t; year += 1) {
        data[year] = this.costIn( year, annualMileage );
                    totalCost += data[year]
    }

    return totalCost;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing `[object Object]` is because `fuel.cost(miles)` does not return the cost value but a `hash` or instance of `cost` class maybe.

Try debugging this javascript on browser's javascript console, by setting a breakpoint at the line:

```
document.getElementById("TotalCost").value = cost;
```

At this moment in Console, just print the `cost` variable. It will list the object structure and you can extract relevant data from that.